# In the Gospels, is there any recorded instance of the Pharisees quoting Scripture?

Tags: gospels, scriptures, pharisees

In a discussion, a family member said that the Pharisees often quoted Scripture.  Do we have any record of this in the Gospels (Matthew, Mark, Luke, and John)?  I don't mean just referring to Biblical concepts or Jewish tradition; I'm looking specifically for direct quotes of the Old Testament.  I can't think of any such case, but I also can't think of a good way to search for such a passage.

Comment: Does John 7:52 count?

Comment: Well, it's something.  Probably not what I'd call a quote for purposes of dialog with family, but good to know about.

Comment: @adv12 Start here: [BibleGateway-Quick search: Pharisees](https://www.biblegateway.com/quicksearch/?qs_version=RSVCE&quicksearch=Pharisees&begin=47&end=73)?

Comment: How about Luke 10:27?  Unclear whether it's a Pharisee or Saducee.

Comment: @FMS: thanks.  I know that's the "hard" way; I will probably resort to checking every instance of "Pharisee" in the NT if no one comes up with anything.  Just thought I'd see if someone could quickly spare me the hard work.

Comment: @BenjaminHoogterp, best so far if it's a Pharisee.  I'll look into it.

Comment: @BenjaminHoogterp: It's just an "expert in the law" -- there's no reason to think it's specifically a Pharisee *or* Saducee.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a verse search question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks to everyone for the comments and to @Narnian and @Flimzy for their answers.  @Narnian, I don't consider the Moses reference a quote, so I was left with the "hard way" suggested by @FMS, which was to individually check every instance of the word "Pharisee" (or "Pharisees") in the Bible.  This turned up 93 hits, which I investigated one at a time.  I viewed each hit verse in context, identified the full passage to which it belonged, and made a table of conversations, speakers, words spoken, and Scripture quoted.  The final result is here:

http://www.the-vardemans.net/andrew/Pharisees.html

I didn't identify a single quote of OT Scripture by the Pharisees, while Jesus quoted the following OT Scriptures, some more than once, all in conversation with Pharisees:

- Hosea 6:6
- Exodus 20:12
- Exodus 21:17
- Isaiah 29:13
- Genesis 1:27
- Genesis 2:24
- Deuteronomy 6:5
- Leviticus 19:18
- Psalm 110:1

Answer (score 5):

Sometimes the Scriptures identify Pharisees specifically, but other times they merely reference chief priests, who may have been Pharisees.  There are a few passages of note:

**The Chief Priests and Scribes cite Micah 5:2 in reference to the birth of the Messiah**

> Gathering together **all the chief priests and scribes** of the people, he inquired of them where the Messiah was to be born. 5 They said to him, “In Bethlehem of Judea; for this is what has been written by the prophet:
>
> 6 ‘And you, Bethlehem, land of Judah,
> Are by no means least among the leaders of Judah;
> For out of you shall come forth a Ruler
> Who will shepherd My people Israel.’”  Matthew 2:4-6 NASB

**The Scribes and Pharisees reference Moses' Teaching on Adultery**

> The **scribes and the Pharisees** brought a woman caught in adultery, and having set her in the center of the court, 4 they said to Him, “Teacher, this woman has been caught in adultery, in the very act. 5 Now **in the Law Moses commanded us to stone such women**; what then do You say?”  John 8:3-5 NASB

Comment: Do you have a reference to support the idea that the chief priests might have included Pharisees?

Comment: Just that in the Matthew passage, it references "chief priests and scribes" without distinguishing whether they were Pharisees or Sadduccees, so that may very well have included both.

Comment: ... or neither.

Comment: My understanding of the Pharisees is not extensive, but their M.O. would almost suggest that they disavowed the literal/historical priesthood.

Answer (score 3):

Paul was a Pharisee, and he quoted scripture extensively in his epistles, but that's not in the Gospels.

I find no other examples of Pharisees directly quoting scripture recorded in the New Testament, based on my search at [Bible Gateway](https://www.biblegateway.com/quicksearch/?quicksearch=pharisee&qs_version=NIV).  But it would be very surprising to think they didn't, as well as they knew the law, which was based on (but not exclusively) scripture.

Comment: After brief review, there are scant enough direct quotes directly attributed to the "Pharisees".  The focus of the Gospels is the "Words in Red", not the words in blue.  While it seems an interesting point, I doubt you could build much doctrine from the point.

Comment: An *expert in the law/lawyer* quotes scripture in Luke 10:27 and the lawyers were insulted alongside the Pharisees in Luke 11:42-48 (which parallels the seven woes against the scribes and the Pharisees in Matthew 23).

Comment: @PaulA.Clayton: I'm not sure what point you're trying to make.

Comment: Not much of a point, just that the lawyers were lumped together with the Pharisees and that reference has a lawyer quoting scriptures.

Comment: @PaulA.Clayton: Usually the Pharisees and "experts in the law" are mentioned separately, which would suggest to me that they are not lumped together.